# SASS doesn't listen

Tags: linux, sass

Good morning. Hello,

Sorry in advance if the question has already been asked, but after two days of research I did not find any solution.

My problem is the following, I reinstalled my linux server machine, all the installation went very well, I then installed ruby-full and SASS, but now when I run the command "--watch" it generates well my css file, but don't listen to the changes, I have to do "ctrl+c" and restart my "--watch" for that changes can be generated....
I tried to uninstall and reinstall, install an old version too, but nothing works...

Do you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Sass version :

```
Sass 3.5.4 (Bleeding Edge)
```

Command --watch

```
sudo sass --watch '/media/sf_websites/projects/minimvc/webroot/templates/css/sass':'/media/sf_websites/projects/minimvc/webroot/templates/css'
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
write /media/sf_websites/projects/minimvc/webroot/templates/css/global.css
write /media/sf_websites/projects/minimvc/webroot/templates/css/global.css.map
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I like the title. My girlfriend thought it's about some guy named Sass that does not listen to you.

Comment: Also having this issue

Answer (score 0):

It might be a permissions problem. You shouldn't need to run `sass` with `sudo`.

Comment: What am I saying is that you should not have to use `sudo`

Comment: Sorry for the time it took me to answer, I didn't have a lot of time, well I didn't find a solution for my problem, but I switched to "node-sass" and everything works very well now:)
Thanks anyway for your help. ^^'